# Where should I define a custom function in CodeIgniter and how can I use it in every page?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I'm a newbie in CodeIgniter. I want to use the following function and needs to be run in every page. I'm calling the function in the top header of the view.  Even though different subviews are loaded in the content below, the navigation bar should load this function in order to count notifications and messages on every run.

```
function count_records_in_table($table, $where) 
{
    $this->db->select('count(id) as rows');
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->db->where($where);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    foreach($query->result() as $r)
    {
       return $r->rows;
    }
}
```

Comment: Db operations are best suitable in model.

Comment: Does that mean I should create a new model class Navigation that extends MY_Model? But I want to be able to retrieve value from different, unrelated tables, not just a particular one.

Comment: create the common model for all pages and put this function on it and load this model in auto load file $autoload['model'] = array('mdl_common'); , finally you can use it in every page just called by $this->mdl_common->count_records_in_table(table_name","where");

Comment: Custom [helper](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/helpers.html#extending-helpers) or [library](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html) would be fine for such a scenario. Autoloading, you could be able to use them all across your application. Check in docs how to create each of those, I linked specific pages/sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first create the common model
then put this function on it and load this model in

```
$autoload['model'] = array('mdl_common');
```

autoload file in config

finally you can use your function by calling model common like this

```
$this->mdl_common->count_records_in_table("table_name","where");
```

you can use in every page you want  try it it will helps .

Answer (score 2):

**Here is suitable  solution**

```
 First create  one file say common.php in  application/libraries/common.php
```

Now  write below code in common.php file

```
        class Common extends CI_Controller 
        {
              public function customFailMessage($msg)
              {
                 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<Response/>');
                 $xml->addChild('status','success');
                 $xml->addChild('msg',"my message");
                 print ($xml->asXML());
                 die;
               }
        }
```

Now call you function from any of your controller like this

```
        class Ws_plan extends CI_Controller 
        {
            public function __construct() 
           {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->library('common');
           }
           public function test()
            {
                        $this->common->customFailMessage();
            }
        }
```

Hope you got idea how to use common function in all controller